# Plotly Dash - syntax error when adding title to figure in dcc.graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Just going through the sample tutorial at the Dash website, I tried to modify the sample code and encountered a syntax error when attempting to add a title to the figure within the second dcc.Graph.

The second dcc.Graph is what I created.  **The code debugger reports that the colon between 'title' and 'Test Progress is a syntax error.** I checked all the brackets and they all line up properly. Please note that I did not include the complete source code as only the dcc.Graph section was relevant to the error.
My guess is that perhaps the wrong type of brackets are being used. But based on the first dcc.Graph, I don't think that is the case.

```
dcc.Graph(
            id='example-graph',
            figure={
                'data': [
                    {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                    {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], \
                     'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
                ],
                'layout': {
                    'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
                }
            }
        ),
dcc.Graph(id='plot1', 
                  figure={          
                plotly_figure, 'layout' : {
                    'title': 'Test Progress'
                    }

                }
            )
```

Additional info:
Added the actual data line that pertains to plotly_figure in the dcc.Graph section and the syntax error no longer appears.

```
plotly_figure = dict(data=[dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,4,8])])

dcc.Graph(id='plot1', 
                  figure = {          
                          'data': [
                    {dict(data=[dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,4,8])])},
                ],
                          'layout' : {
                        'title' : 'Test Progress'
                    }

                }
            )
```

Solution to the problem:
Proper syntax for plotly_fig is as follows:

```
plotly_fig = [dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,4,8])]
dcc.Graph(id='plot1', 
                      figure={          
                    plotly_fig, 'layout' : {
                        'title': 'Test Progress'
                        }

                    }
                )
```

Comment: You have something wrong in your second figure:`figure={ plotly_figure, `, remove that.

Comment: @T4rk1n, based on your suggestion I removed the reference to plotly_figure and instead include the actual line of code that plotly_figure references and the syntax error no longer appear. Does this provide you with additional clues to why I got the syntax error with by referencing the variable name?